# ¿Como poner una id a un tr desde array?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, datatables, datatable

Como puedo poner los id que venga desde la base de datos a los tr desde el controlador ya que desde ahi se imprime

```html
//CONTROLADOR 

public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->Prorrateo_model->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no   = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $traba) {

            $originalDate1 = $traba->fechaInTraba;
            $newDate1      = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate1));
            $originalDate2 = $traba->fechaCese;
            $newDate2      = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate2));

            $no++;
            $row   = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $traba->empleado;
            $row[] = $traba->dniTraba;
            $row[] = $traba->nCargo;
            $row[] = $traba->nArea;
            $row[] = $traba->emailTraba;
            $row[] = $traba->celTraba;
            $row[] = $traba->direcTraba;
            $row[] = $newDate1;
            $row[] = $newDate2;
            $row[] = $traba->nContrata;
            $row[] = $traba->nSispension;
            $row[] = $traba->horaIng;
            $row[] = $traba->horaSali;
            $row[] = $traba->JorLaboral;
            $row[] = $traba->remuneracion;
            $row[] = $traba->numlabor;
            $row[] = $traba->asigfamilia;
            $row[] = $traba->thextra;
            $row[] = $traba->boniordi;
            $row[] = $traba->tconcepremu;
            $row[] = $traba->remuvacapro;
            $row[] = $traba->gratiprorra;
            $row[] = $traba->subsidios;
            $row[] = $traba->conditraba;
            $row[] = $traba->vales;
            $row[] = $traba->movilidad;
            $row[] = $traba->comisiones;
            $row[] = $traba->boniextra;
            $row[] = $traba->utilidades;
            $row[] = $traba->remutotal;
            $row[] = $traba->renta5tac;
            $row[] = $traba->pensionesp;
            $row[] = $traba->renta4tac;
            $row[] = $traba->rejudicial;
            $row[] = $traba->tardanza;
            $row[] = $traba->otros;
            $row[] = $traba->totaldsctos;
            $row[] = $traba->essalud;
            $row[] = $traba->tnetopagar;
            $row[] = $traba->ctsprorrateo;
            $row[] = $traba->smeprivado;
            $row[] = $traba->taporteEmp;
            $row[] = $traba->despagarterceros;
            $row[] = $traba->tgremuneracion;
            $row[] = $traba->adremuneracion;
            $row[] = $traba->observaciones;

            $row[]  = '<center><button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-teal waves-effect editar" href="javascript:void(0)" data=' . $traba->idProrrateo . ' onclick="edit_person(' . "'" . $traba->idProrrateo . "'" . ')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Editar</button>   <button  type="button" class="btn btn-xs bg-red waves-effect" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_person(' . "'" . $traba->idProrrateo . "'" . ')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Eliminar</button></center>';
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw"            => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal"    => $this->Prorrateo_model->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->Prorrateo_model->count_filtered(),
            "data"            => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

```js
//FUNCION PARA LISTAR 
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#table').DataTable({
   "scrollX": true,
   "scrollY":        "245px",
   "lengthMenu": [[5, 15, 25, 50,100, -1], [5, 15, 25, 50,100, "Todo"]],
   "scrollCollapse": true,
        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.
        "language": {
          "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
          "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados en su busqueda",
          "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar registros",
          "info": "Mostrando  de _START_ al _END_  de  _TOTAL_ registros",
          "infoEmpty": "No existen registros",
          "infoFiltered": "",
          "search": "Buscar:",
          "processing": "Procesando...:",
          "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Último",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
          },
        },
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
          "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>prorrateo/ajax_list",
          "type": "POST"
        },
        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
          },
          ],


        });

});
```

```html
<!--VISTA DE LA TABLA -->


<div class="body">
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" cellspacing="0" style="min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; width: 1000px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 10px;">ITEM</th>
        <th style="width: 250px;">EMPLEADO</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">DNI</th>
        <th style="width: 200px;">CARGO</th>
        <th style="width: 200px;">ÁREA</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">CORREO</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">CELULAR</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">DIRECCIÓN</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">FECHA INGRESO</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">FECHA CESE</th>
        <th style="width: 200px;">TIPO CONTRATACION</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">SISTEMA PENSION</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">HORA INGRESO</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">HORA SALIDA</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">JORNADA LABORAL</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">REMUNERACION BASICA</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;"># DE DIAS LABORADOS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">ASIGNACION FAMILIAR</th>
        <th style="width: 200px;">COMISIONES</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">TOTAL HORAS EXTRAS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">BONIFICACION ORDINARIA</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">TOTAL CONCEPTOS REMUNERATIVOS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">REMUNERACION VACACIONAL PRORRATEADA</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">GRATIFICACIONES PRORRATEADAS</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">SUBSIDIOS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">CONDICION TRABAJO</th>
        <th style="width: 100px;">VALES</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">MOVILIDAD</th>
        <th style="width: 250px;">BONIFICAION EXTRAORDINARIA</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">UTILIDADES</th>
        <th style="width: 250px;">REMUNERACION TOTAL</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">RENTA DE 5TA. CATEGORIA</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">PRENSIONES PREVISIONALES</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">RENTA DE 4TA. CATEGORIA</th>
        <th style="width: 250px;">RETENCION JUDICIAL</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">TARDANZAS</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">OTROS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">ADELANTOS DE REMUNERACION</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">TOTAL DSCTOS.</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">TOTAL NETO A PAGAR</th>
        <th style="width: 150px;">ESSALUD</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">CTS PRORRATEADOS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">SEGURO MEDICO PRIVADO</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">TOTAL APORTES EMPLEADOR</th>
        <th style="width: 400px;">TOTAL DESCUENTOS REALIZADOS A PAGAR A TERCEROS</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">TOTAL GASTO REMUNERACION</th>
        <th style="width: 300px;">OBSERVACIONES</th>
        <th style="width:200px; " align="center">OPCION</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTable tiene una manera automática de agregar el atributo `id` a los `tr` que se generan con la `data` que alimenta la tabla, lo único que debes hacer es enviar la propiedad `DT_RowId` dentro de cada elemento que conforma el objeto, quedando dicho objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1,
  "recordsFiltered": 1,
  "data": [{
    "DT_RowId": "1",
    "item_1": "Valor 1",
    "item_2": "Valor 2"
  }, {
    "DT_RowId": "2",
    "item_1": "Valor 1.1",
    "item_2": "Valor 2.1"
  }]
}
```

Aunque esta es la propiedad por defecto, también puede ser cambiada por alguna propiedad específica especial, de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1,
  "recordsFiltered": 1,
  "data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "item_1": "Valor 1",
    "item_2": "Valor 2"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "item_1": "Valor 1.1",
    "item_2": "Valor 2.1"
  }]
}

$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": '/api/prueba',
    "rowId": 'id'
});
```

La propiedad `rowId` también recibe como valor el índice del valor a usar en caso de que la data no sea un `array` de objetos (que de hecho es así como lo tienes):

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 1,
  "recordsFiltered": 1,
  "data": [[
    "1",
    "Valor 1",
    "Valor 2"
  ], [
    "2",
    "Valor 1.1",
    "Valor 2.1"
  ]]
}

$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": '/api/prueba',
    "rowId": '0',
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [0], //Ocultamos la primera columna, donde se muestra el id
        "visible": false
    }],
});
```

Hay dos aspectos importantes que tener en cuenta a la hora de generar los `id`:

> El valor debe ser único entre todos los ID en el subárbol de inicio del elemento y debe contener al menos un carácter.
>
> El valor no debe contener ningún espacio de caracteres.

Para más información puedes consultar [DataTables - rowId](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId)